# Can I simplify a repeated measures Anova with only 2 time points?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have a scale variable, collected in 2 separated times, t1 (pre-test) and t2 (post-test).

My question is, must I use a repeated measures Anova, or can I use a basic Anova with only one factor: the difference between two values (t2-t1) ?

Comment: Is T1 actually a "pre" value and T2 a "post" value? Or are they *true* repeated (post-baseline) measures.

Comment: Yes, t1 is a pre-value and t2 is a post-value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Rey0bs possible duplicate here? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs